# Add a line break at the half of text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to add a line break `<br/>` at the half of each block of text I have.
Meaning that if I have a tweet like this : "Google scientists find evidence of machine learning" it would be like this :

`"Google scientists find evidence < br/> of machine learning"`

How can I count the number of words in my string, divide this number by two and add a break in jQuery ?

Thanks

An example :

```
<span class="tweet-text">Nara Wants To Build A Better Recommendation Platform, Starts With Restaurants And A $4 Million Series...</span>
```

needs to become

```
<span class="tweet-text">Nara Wants To Build A Better Recommendation < br/> Platform, Starts With Restaurants And A $4 Million Series...</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
var words = "Google scientists find evidence of machine learning";
var arrofwords = words.split(" ");
var middle = arrofwords.length / 2;
arrofwords.splice(middle,0,"<br/>");
var output = arrofwords.join(" ");
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XHL7W/)

It splits the sentence using the spaces, inserts a `<br/>` after the middle word and joins it again ....

(Thanks [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) for suggestion in comment)

Althouth this has some issues - it doesnt put the `<br/>` where you wanted it ... and wouldn't be the most efficient for long sentences

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest counting the amount of characters in the string, finding the space nearest to the 50% point and splitting the string there. Then just render back the string with a break inserted.

Comment: Felix's solution above is faster.

Comment: I deleted it, I don't think it's faster. Depends on whether splitting a string is faster than finding a character. I don't think so. Besides, finding the center of the string by characters instead of words is probably more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

```
function wordwrap( str, int_width, str_break, cut ) {   // Wraps a string to a given number of characters
    // 
    // +   original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)
    // +   improved by: Nick Callen

    var i, j, s, r = str.split("\n");
    if(int_width > 0) for(i in r){
        for(s = r[i], r[i] = ""; s.length > int_width;
            j = cut ? int_width : (j = s.substr(0, int_width).match(/\S*$/)).input.length - j[0].length || int_width,
            r[i] += s.substr(0, j) + ((s = s.substr(j)).length ? str_break : "")
        );
        r[i] += s;
    }
    return r.join("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin automatically breaks your line of text nicely in 2 when the container is smaller than the text width:

https://github.com/SumoSoft/PrettyBreak